# Error "permissionsets/MYPERMSETNAME'S.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" when deploying using ANT

Tags: deployment, ant, permission-sets, mdapideploy

We are currently using Azure Pipelines as our tool for CI/CD.

For our Deployments, we are currently ANT and everything was working fine until we added "Permission Sets" and "Profiles" (using the wildcard) to our package.xml as below:

```
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
   </types>
```

After we added the PermSets and Profiles, we ran our deployment and started receiving the "Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" for every single Permission Set.

The sandbox we are deploying to is exactly as Prod, as we just refreshed it. Nothing is really different.

As per Salesforce documentation found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328226&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), "There are six documented, specific examples of when this error can occur.  They are detailed below, with possible cause/suggestions. **However, the error may occur for a new, undocumented scenario also.**"

After Googling it a lot, most of the scenarios are related to a user not having the right access to a specific record/object/record type, etc...

In this case, our user is an API Only user and the error doesn't occur for the Profiles, only for Permission Sets.

The complete ANT log is below:

```
2020-10-13T16:54:57.8664560Z ##[section]Starting: Ant
2020-10-13T16:55:04.5721873Z deployCode:
2020-10-13T16:55:13.1146051Z [sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
2020-10-13T16:55:13.1147051Z [sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0Af0q00000gf2gOCAQ
2020-10-13T16:55:13.1166019Z [sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
2020-10-13T16:55:13.2571146Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
2020-10-13T16:55:23.4117905Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:55:33.5329951Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (66/1678)  -- Processing Type: CustomObject
2020-10-13T16:55:43.6660074Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (66/1678)  -- Processing Type: CustomObject
2020-10-13T16:55:53.7918484Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:56:04.7966720Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:56:14.9897248Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (78/1678)  -- Processing Account.ATMAnnualRevenue__c
2020-10-13T16:56:25.2741712Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1439/1678)  -- Processing Type: ApexClass
2020-10-13T16:56:35.4665922Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1439/1678)  -- Processing Type: ApexClass
2020-10-13T16:56:45.7207013Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1506/1678)  -- Processing Type: ApexTrigger
2020-10-13T16:56:55.9729987Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1525/1678)  -- Processing Type: Profile
2020-10-13T16:57:06.1923607Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:57:16.4393361Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (1579/1678)  -- Processing Type: PermissionSet
2020-10-13T16:57:26.6728477Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:57:26.6732859Z [sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-13T16:57:26.6733624Z [sf:deploy] Component Failures:
2020-10-13T16:57:26.6734617Z [sf:deploy] 1.  permissionsets/API_User_IssueTrak_Fields.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:26.6735631Z [sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1519843Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1521570Z [sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1522172Z [sf:deploy] Component Failures:
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1523162Z [sf:deploy] 2.  permissionsets/Access_to_CRF.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1524301Z [sf:deploy] 3.  permissionsets/Access_to_Do_Not_Call.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1525387Z [sf:deploy] 4.  permissionsets/Access_to_Opportunities.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1526471Z [sf:deploy] 5.  permissionsets/Beta_Project.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1527521Z [sf:deploy] 6.  permissionsets/Access_to_SPA_records.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1528591Z [sf:deploy] 7.  permissionsets/Albany_Edit_Tasks.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1529744Z [sf:deploy] 8.  permissionsets/Audit_Fields_and_Load_to_Inactive_Users.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:57:37.1530818Z [sf:deploy] 9.  permissionsets/BIA_Requests.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:48.9142677Z [sf:deploy] 84.  permissionsets/SmartGrowth_Advisor_Field_Edit_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
.
.
.
2020-10-13T16:58:48.9143783Z [sf:deploy] 85.  permissionsets/Service_Console_App.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:48.9144847Z [sf:deploy] 86.  permissionsets/SFC_ID_Update_access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:48.9145834Z [sf:deploy] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-13T16:58:59.1640090Z [sf:deploy] Request Status: Failed
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4756131Z 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4757061Z BUILD FAILED
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4757509Z /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Salesforce/buildfiles/build.xml:18: 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4758035Z *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4758469Z Request ID: 0Af0q00000gf2gOCAQ
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4758826Z 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4759201Z All Component Failures:
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4760482Z 1.  permissionsets/API_User_IssueTrak_Fields.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4761506Z 2.  permissionsets/Access_to_CRF.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4762550Z 3.  permissionsets/Access_to_Add_On_Product_RT.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4763586Z 4.  permissionsets/Access_to_Opportunities.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4764591Z 5.  permissionsets/Beta_Project.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4765576Z 6.  permissionsets/Access_to_SPA_records.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4766573Z 7.  permissionsets/Albany_Edit_Tasks.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4769029Z 8.  permissionsets/Audit_Fields_and_Load_to_Inactive_Users.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4769842Z 9.  permissionsets/BIA_Requests.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4770626Z 10.  permissionsets/Access_to_Do_Not_Call.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4771574Z 11.  permissionsets/Access_to_Projects_CRF.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4772314Z 12.  permissionsets/CRO.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4773099Z 13.  permissionsets/CRF_Field_Permission_Expansion.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4773950Z 14.  permissionsets/CDA_Edit_Tasks.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4774916Z 15.  permissionsets/Beta_Project_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4775763Z 16.  permissionsets/Case_permission_override.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4776581Z 17.  permissionsets/Client_care_create_ticket.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4777397Z 18.  permissionsets/Client_Care_Manager_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4778277Z 19.  permissionsets/Chatter_Plus_Ticket_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4779124Z 20.  permissionsets/Changing_CSR_Assignment_on_a_case.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4779932Z 21.  permissionsets/Change_CRF_Status.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4780851Z 22.  permissionsets/Cases_Modify_All.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4781674Z 23.  permissionsets/Community_Access_for_CO_OP_Staff.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4782501Z 24.  permissionsets/Community_Manager_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4783338Z 25.  permissionsets/Contract_Info.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4784079Z 26.  permissionsets/Create_SPA.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4784850Z 27.  permissionsets/Custom_Metadata_Types.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4785680Z 28.  permissionsets/Create_All_Cases.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4786442Z 29.  permissionsets/Covera_Tasks.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4787282Z 30.  permissionsets/Corp_Dev_Account_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4788108Z 31.  permissionsets/Conversion_Analysis_access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4788916Z 32.  permissionsets/Create_Client_Care_Case.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4789789Z 33.  permissionsets/Dashboards_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4790545Z 34.  permissionsets/Delete_Cases.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4791323Z 35.  permissionsets/Delete_Chatter_Posts.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4792339Z 36.  permissionsets/Delete_Contacts.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4793144Z 37.  permissionsets/Delete_files_and_folder.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4793963Z 38.  permissionsets/Executive_Concierge_Contact.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4794886Z 39.  permissionsets/Edit_Access_on_Co_op_Relationship.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4795743Z 40.  permissionsets/Edit_Access_on_Description_field.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4796626Z 41.  permissionsets/Edit_Access_on_Quota_Field.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4797423Z 42.  permissionsets/Edit_Time_Tracking.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4798208Z 43.  permissionsets/Edit_Access_on_CRF.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4799140Z 44.  permissionsets/Expanded_CRF_Permissions.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4799943Z 45.  permissionsets/FI_Record_Type_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4800702Z 46.  permissionsets/Flow_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4801562Z 47.  permissionsets/Full_Access_to_Dashboards.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4802363Z 48.  permissionsets/IMO_Create_Esclations.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4803168Z 49.  permissionsets/Manage_Dynamic_Dashboards.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4804012Z 50.  permissionsets/LEx_Report_Builder.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4804851Z 51.  permissionsets/Lead_Conversion.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4805683Z 52.  permissionsets/Lightning_Experience_And_Classic_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4806593Z 53.  permissionsets/Lightning_Experience_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4807493Z 54.  permissionsets/Intake_Team_Managers_Edit_Issue_Trak_Ticket_Number.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4808422Z 55.  permissionsets/Manage_List_Views.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4809267Z 56.  permissionsets/Manage_Public_Templates.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4810095Z 57.  permissionsets/Manage_Salesforce_CRM_Content.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4810966Z 58.  permissionsets/Manage_Service_Wave.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4811739Z 59.  permissionsets/Manage_Tickets.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4812521Z 60.  permissionsets/New_Collabria_Account.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4813338Z 61.  permissionsets/Modify_All.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4814103Z 62.  permissionsets/Modify_All_Accounts.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4814916Z 63.  permissionsets/Modify_All_Evaluation_Models.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4816997Z 64.  permissionsets/MyCOOP2_Community_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4817877Z 65.  permissionsets/Manage_Users.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4818686Z 66.  permissionsets/New_Platform_Sales_Record_Type.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4819578Z 67.  permissionsets/Opportunities_Modify_All.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4820406Z 68.  permissionsets/Opportunity_Record_Type_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4821238Z 69.  permissionsets/Platform_CSE_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4899085Z 70.  permissionsets/Power_SF_CRO_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4900307Z 71.  permissionsets/Platform_Ticket_Read_Only.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4902848Z 72.  permissionsets/Platforms_Access_to_CRF.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4903682Z 73.  permissionsets/Platforms_Manager.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4904453Z 74.  permissionsets/Platforms_User.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4905301Z 75.  permissionsets/Platform_Ticket_Create_and_Edit_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4906208Z 76.  permissionsets/Service_Console_App.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4907115Z 77.  permissionsets/SFC_ID_Update_access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4908027Z 78.  permissionsets/Salesforce_Project_Tickets_Task_Managers.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4909048Z 79.  permissionsets/Schedule_and_Subscirbe_Reports.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4910012Z 80.  permissionsets/SmartGrowth_Advisor_Field_Edit_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4910895Z 81.  permissionsets/Remain_in_Classic.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4911916Z 82.  permissionsets/PrePaid_Pricebook_Edit.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4913268Z 83.  permissionsets/Product_Office_Request_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4914203Z 84.  permissionsets/Product_Office_Request_Access_Master.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4915048Z 85.  permissionsets/Product_Staff_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4915872Z 86.  permissionsets/Smart_Growth_Opps.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4925771Z 87.  permissionsets/TimeTrackingDeleteModifyAll.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4926900Z 88.  permissionsets/Transfer_Record_Ownership.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4927696Z 89.  permissionsets/Type_of_Case.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4928477Z 90.  permissionsets/View_All_Data.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4929250Z 91.  permissionsets/Wave_Analytics_Users.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4930053Z 92.  permissionsets/TimeTrackingDelete.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4930891Z 93.  permissionsets/Sprint_Managers_Read_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4931694Z 94.  permissionsets/TMG_Access_Now_Admin.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4932574Z 95.  permissionsets/TMG_Client_Solutions_Case_Record_Type_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4933395Z 96.  permissionsets/Ticket_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4934166Z 97.  permissionsets/Write_BIA_read_SPA.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4935028Z 98.  permissionsets/sfdcInternalInt__sfdc_activityplatform.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4935885Z 99.  permissionsets/zAgile_Connect_Full_Access.permissionset -- Error: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4936354Z 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4936561Z *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4936734Z 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4937006Z    at com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask.logFailedDeploy(DeployTask.java:178)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4937436Z    at com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask.handleResponse(DeployTask.java:150)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4937910Z    at com.salesforce.ant.SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.runTask(SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.java:92)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4938350Z    at com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:63)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4938760Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4939156Z    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4939556Z    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4940045Z    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4940553Z    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4940959Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4941365Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4941733Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4942108Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4942515Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4942948Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4943400Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4943853Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4944245Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4944602Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4945088Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4945488Z    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4945727Z 
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4945918Z Total time: 3 minutes 56 seconds
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4946466Z The process '/usr/bin/ant' failed with exit code 1
2020-10-13T16:58:59.4979911Z ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/ant' failed with exit code 1
2020-10-13T16:58:59.5018091Z ##[section]Finishing: Ant
```

Nothing more is logged under "Deployment Status" other than what is already in the ANT log.

Has anybody seen this before?

Thanks.